# how to show value after select 2 option php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how to show 2 value 2 filed in my database after select 2 option from selcetion like my ex on below
[Ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/617Ae.png)

now i can select multi option but don't know how to show both filed after select

ex. option(1) pick Manga >>> option(2) pick one piece > show both filed country img and author picture

here my ajax code and fetch code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.action').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var action = $(this).attr("id");
            var query = $(this).val();
            var result = '';
            if(action == 'book')
            {
                result = 'nk';
            }
            $.ajax({
                url:'fetch.php',
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action, query:query},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#'+result).html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

featch code vvv

```
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    include('database_connection.php');

    $output = '';

    if($_POST["action"] == 'book')
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT nk FROM oppa 
        WHERE book = :book 
        GROUP BY nk
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':book'     =>  $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $output .= '<option value="">Select Name</option>';
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '<option value="'.$row["nk"].'">'.$row["nk"].'</option>';
        }
    }
    if($_POST["action"] == 'nk')
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT co FROM oppa 
        WHERE nk = :nk
        ";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':nk'       =>  $_POST["query"]
            )
        );
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();


    }
    echo $output;
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Man, it's hard to understand what you need from here, but look at your second `if` the `$result` variable is not used, may be it will help

Comment: i mean when i select first option and then go to select second option then show 2 value from my database like i select (1) manga > (2) onepiece then show flag of japan and show picture of author

Comment: Maybe you can select them when you first select a manga and then just display them on the client side when user hits the second option? like `SELECT nk, co FROM oppa WHERE book = :book GROUP BY nk`. If that makes any sense. No idea what `nk` and `co` means and how they're stored.